# H264 encoding and decoding using Videotoolbox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, video-toolbox

I was testing the encoding and decoding using videotoolbox, to convert the captured frames to H264 and using that data to display it in AVSampleBufferdisplayLayer.

error here while decompress CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets with error code -12712

I follow [this code from mobisoftinfotech.com](https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/h264-encode-decode-using-videotoolbox/)

```
status = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets(
    kCFAlloc‌​‌ atorDefault, 2,
    (const uint8_t const)parameterSetPointers, 
    parameterSetSizes, 4, &_formatDesc);
```

videoCompressionTest; can anyone figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you did figure out the problem yet. However, I found 2 places in your code that leading to the error. After fixed them and run locally your test app, it seems to be working fine. (Tested with Xcode 9.4.1, MacOS 10.13)

**The first one** is in `-(void)CompressAndConvertToData:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer` method where the while loop should be like this

```
while (bufferOffset < blockBufferLength - AVCCHeaderLength) {
    // Read the NAL unit length
    uint32_t NALUnitLength = 0;
    memcpy(&NALUnitLength, bufferDataPointer + bufferOffset, AVCCHeaderLength);
    // Convert the length value from Big-endian to Little-endian
    NALUnitLength = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(NALUnitLength);
    // Write start code to the elementary stream
    [elementaryStream appendBytes:startCode length:startCodeLength];
    // Write the NAL unit without the AVCC length header to the elementary stream
    [elementaryStream appendBytes:bufferDataPointer + bufferOffset + AVCCHeaderLength
                           length:NALUnitLength];
    // Move to the next NAL unit in the block buffer
    bufferOffset += AVCCHeaderLength + NALUnitLength;
}

uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t*)[elementaryStream bytes];
int size = (int)[elementaryStream length];

[self receivedRawVideoFrame:bytes withSize:size];
```

**The second place** is the decompression code where you process for NALU type 8, the block of code in `if(nalu_type == 8)` statement. This is a tricky one. 
To fix it, update

```
for (int i = _spsSize + 12; i < _spsSize + 50; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = _spsSize + 12; i < _spsSize + 12 + 50; i++)
```

And you are freely to remove this hack

```
//was crashing here
    if(_ppsSize == 0)
        _ppsSize = 4;
```

Why? Lets print out the frame packet format.

`po frame
▿ 4282 elements
  - 0 : 0
  - 1 : 0
  - 2 : 0
  - 3 : 1
  - 4 : 39
  - 5 : 100
  - 6 : 0
  - 7 : 30
  - 8 : 172
  - 9 : 86
  - 10 : 193
  - 11 : 112
  - 12 : 247
  - 13 : 151
  - 14 : 64
  - 15 : 0
  - 16 : 0
  - 17 : 0
  - 18 : 1
  - 19 : 40
  - 20 : 238
  - 21 : 60
  - 22 : 176
  - 23 : 0
  - 24 : 0
  - 25 : 0
  - 26 : 1
  - 27 : 6
  - 28 : 5
  - 29 : 35
  - 30 : 71
  - 31 : 86
  - 32 : 74
  - 33 : 220
  - 34 : 92
  - 35 : 76
  - 36 : 67
  - 37 : 63
  - 38 : 148
  - 39 : 239
  - 40 : 197
  - 41 : 17
  - 42 : 60
  - 43 : 209
  - 44 : 67
  - 45 : 168
  - 46 : 0
  - 47 : 0
  - 48 : 3
  - 49 : 0
  - 50 : 0
  - 51 : 3
  - 52 : 0
  - 53 : 2
  - 54 : 143
  - 55 : 92
  - 56 : 40
  - 57 : 1
  - 58 : 221
  - 59 : 204
  - 60 : 204
  - 61 : 221
  - 62 : 2
  - 63 : 0
  - 64 : 76
  - 65 : 75
  - 66 : 64
  - 67 : 128
  - 68 : 0
  - 69 : 0
  - 70 : 0
  - 71 : 1
  - 72 : 37
  - 73 : 184
  - 74 : 32
  - 75 : 1
  - 76 : 223
  - 77 : 205
  - 78 : 248
  - 79 : 30
  - 80 : 231
… more`

The first NALU start code `if (nalu_type == 7)` is 0, 0, 0, 1 from index of 15 to 18. The next 0, 0, 0, 1 (from 23 to 26) is type 6, type 8 NALU start code is from 68 to 71. That why I modify the for loop a bit to scan from start index (_spsSize + 12) with a range of 50.

I haven't fully tested your code to make sure encode and decode work properly as expected. However, I hope this finding would help you.
By the way, if there is any misunderstanding, I would love to learn from your comments.